# Вызов View или ViewController в обход storyboard iOS objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, controller, view

Имеется NavigationController, в проекте используется Storyboard.

Возникла потребность вызвать из любого окна (пока что их ок 10, но количество увеличится примерно вдвое) некое окно - основное меню с возможностью навигации. Очевидно, что рисовать путь от каждого окна в storyboard к окну меню - не есть хорошо. Откуда и возникла потребность вызвать окно (push) иными средствами, нежели performSegueWithIdentifier.

Пробовал использовать конструкцию типа:

```
Menu *menu = [[Menu alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:menu animated:YES];
```

И даже заходит в viewDidLoad вызываемого класса, но после - вылетает с SIGABRT.

P.S. По SplitViewController не найдется ли чего интересного и желательно на русском?

Comment: @AlEX, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Можно всё поменять и не использовать StoryBoard для  этого контроллера. Использовать для него xib файл и создавать его инстанс методом initWithNib....

Answer (score 2):

Задайте для `UIViewController` **storyboardID** *(это на той же вкладке, где и класс задается)*.

Дальше в коде, где это необходимо:

```
if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewControllerIdentifier") as? MyViewController {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    /* ну или presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) */
}
```

Да, если что, на Objective-C:

```
MyViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated: true];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну так сделайте Slideout menu и на навигейшнконтроллер поцепите значек меню, и будет вам меню вызываться в любом месте. Библиотек по Slideout menu полно.